# How can I ask the user if they want to use my search script again to search for something else?

Tags: python, loops

There are a couple of requirements in my assignment where the "Admin" who is supposed to use my program wants to search for multiple specific records from txt files. I have already done that part but the thing that I want is when he searches for a specified file I want to ask him if he wants to search for another one using a loop or whatever.

```
if name=="Amer" or name=="174093" or name=="4.3":
    f=open("Amer.txt" ,"r")
    print(f.read())

elif name=="Barbara" or name=="642921" or name=="4.8":
    f=open("Barbara.txt" ,"r")
    print(f.read())

elif name=="Diluc" or name=="642921" or name=="3.4":
    f=open("Diluc.txt" ,"r")
    print(f.read())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while True:
    #name = input()

    if name=="Amer" or name=="174093" or name=="4.3":
        f=open("Amer.txt" ,"r")
        print(f.read())
    
    elif name=="Barbara" or name=="642921" or name=="4.8":
        f=open("Barbara.txt" ,"r")
        print(f.read())
    
    elif name=="Diluc" or name=="642921" or name=="3.4":
        f=open("Diluc.txt" ,"r")
        print(f.read())

    choice = input("Do you want to search once more? Y/N ")

    if choice == "N":
        break
```

You can you this `while True:` statement. It means it will loop indefinitely until the user input choice is equal to "N". When that happens, it will `break` the loop and exit.

Comment: Alright so it worked and all but when I increased the number if (elif) the choice variable started to give me errors and idk why

Comment: give more info please